# Is there any way to convert C++ program into ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, c++

Is there any way to convert C++ program into ASP.NET?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No there is not.

You have some options though:

- You can create a managed [C++ / CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) DLL from your C++ code.
- You can create a C++ Win32 DLL and use [p/invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446536.aspx) to import the DLL functions into your ASP.NET page.
- Re-write your code in C# or another .Net language.

Comment: If your program is complex and you don't have time or the real need to rewrite, then this is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not at all possible. It's like converting an apple to a television.